# Weird django REST APIs behaviour

Tags: amazon-web-services, django, elastic-beanstalk

We are having django application, which is hosted on AWS Elastic Beanstalk.
It is connected to RDS.

**Application Server:** c5.4xlarge

**RDS:** postgreSQL 9.5 (m5.4xlarge)

*The issue is APIs are sometimes returning 500 and sometimes 200
even though the request params are exactly same.*

That is causing Elastic Beanstalk to degrade every now and then.

I tested the APIs with all possible requests on my local by connecting to Cloud database.
But did not receive a single 500 error.

Same app is there on Test environment and it is not causing a single 500.

There is no load on the RDS when EB degrades.

So, it seems application is not the issue here.

**Could it be due to Application Server resources?**

Please help.

**Cloudwatch References:**

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Your webserver and database slow query logs don't say anything?

Comment: @ceejayoz Webserver's https/access _log has the 500 errors for few APIs. But when I execute those same APIs on my local, I do not get 500.